# how to scrape the URL on Scrapy Following Links

Tags: python, scrapy

I am confused how to scrape the URL itself in following links scrapy.
I do crawling on this page [here](https://nasional.sindonews.com/topic/9695/pemilu-2019/26)

```
import scrapy
from ..items import SkripsiItem

class SkripsiSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'skripsi'
    start_urls = ['https://nasional.sindonews.com/topic/9695/pemilu-2019/']

    def parse(self, response):

        for href in response.css('.lnk-t a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_author)

        for href in response.css('.newpaging li:nth-child(4) a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

    def parse_author(self, response):

        items = SkripsiItem()
        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).get(default='').strip()

        content = response.xpath(".//div[@class='vidy-embed']/descendant::text()").extract()

        items['title'] = extract_with_css('h1::text'),
        items['author'] = extract_with_css('.author a::text'),
        items['time'] = extract_with_css('time::text'),
        items['imagelink'] = extract_with_css('.article img::attr(src)'),
        items['content'] = ''.join(content),

        yield items
```

how to scrape every url that is visited at the following link, which is in the code above is `.lnk -t a :: attr (href)`

Comment: It's not clear what do you want but as I see you have an issue with pagination processing.

Comment: sorry my question is confusing and I'm not very good in English, so in the spider I've managed to do the following links, and can save 5 data, but I want to save the URL too. I still can't do it

Comment: Use `response.url` to get current URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save `items['url'] = response.url` in the `parse_author` function.